# Duplicating columns in an inheritance model

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, database-design

I have two tables that model an inheritance relationship. This is expressed by a foreign key constraint on `Derived.Id` referencing `Base.Id`. Some columns in `Base` are essentially duplicated in `Derived` so they can be referenced in unique constraints and compound foreign keys. I would like to ensure the values for these columns are the same in both tables. Ideally, this would be done with a compound foreign key on `Id` + the column. But this prevents the values from being changed--it's a catch-22 scenario.

How could I ensure these columns have the same values in both tables *and* allow them to be updated? I have complete flexibility, so I can change the tables' schemas or do whatever else is necessary to make this possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would only keep the columns in one of the tables, `base` if it applies to all objects.
Can you give an example of the necessity of duplicating your columns with a concrete example, like base = car, has VIN, derived = myCar, has VIN.

Also, if the duplicated columns are part of the keys, use cascade update.

Comment: As an example, all `Base`'s have a `Category`. But `Category` must be in `Derived` to put a unique constraint on `Category` + `Name` (which is only in `Derived`). Regarding cascading updates, unfortunately that's off limits due to the ORM I'm required to use.

Comment: When I've done that kind of thing in the past, I've just had category in the base table and had the unique constraint on the name field, as the derived table contained only one category as each category had different columns.

Comment: Actually, if every derived category has a Name (or anything else,) you can keep that in the base table.

Comment: cdeszaq recommended a single table also, but it doesn't work for the reason I mentioned in the comments on his answer.

Comment: The best answer in my situation (and the simplest) is to use cascading updates.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than have  2nd table, I would just have all of the columns `Derived` needs inside the `Base` table and set those columns to be nullable. If you add a discriminator column as well to determine if the particular record represents a `Base` object or a `Derived` object, you are all set.

You can set up whatever constraints you need and don't have to deal with duplicate data getting out of sync, which is why the single-table-per-hierarchy is the default method Hibernate (and NHibernate) use for mapping inheritance.

Comment: What if you want a table to reference `Derived` in a foreign key constraint? You can't do that with a single table + discriminator column.

Comment: If you mean that you need another object to have a refference to a `Derived` and not just a `Base`, you can do it a number of different ways. One way is to have one of the `Derived` columns be an ID column, separate from the `Base` ID column, with a uniqueness constraint on it, and make the FK off of that. The other option is to make the FK off of the `Base` PK and an additional `Derived`-only field.

Comment: Your latter suggestion is a "weak guarantee", in my mind, because if the "`Derived`-only field" is null the constraint wouldn't be enforced.

Comment: Yes, it isn't ideal since the DB can't enforce the data to be fully correct (at least not easily...), but the DB's ability to maintain absolute control (in an ORM environment especially) always breaks down at some point. The 1st solution I proposed is the better choice I think.